# How to solve this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Question:
[image: http://imgur.com/a/ArcyP]

The problem is I always stuck at this kind of problems can you tell me how to solve this problem ?

I think about using Thevenin or Norton but circuit seems to confusing.

Comment: Where do you stuck?

Comment: Please show your calculations so someone might spot a mistake.

Comment: Simplify everything you know how to, then come back after you've shown some effort.

Comment: If you straighten out the parts drawn at funny angles, the circuit will appear much simpler - the three resistors on the left are all in parallel.

Comment: @PeterBennett yeah i realised that but i have questions like : 1) Can i eliminate 2 voltage sources at left like there is 2(+_-) and 1(-_+) voltage source are those eliminate eachother ? 2) if we use thevenin and make current sources open terminal would current still go through the resistors (50-100-150 the ones with on the same cable with current sources) ?

Comment: I can see 10 simplifications.

Comment: @Bence kaulics i decided to use thevenin but i dont know that would it solve the circuit. I mean when i draw current sources as open terminal should i still sum the resistors that in same line with current sources ? Because current wont flow through open terminals so would it eliminate those resistors or should i still add them to Rth ?

Comment: Some hints: (1) R's in parallel to voltage source can be ignored (i.e. they don't affect the voltage across the source) (2) R's in series to current sources can be ignored (i.e. they don't affect the current through the sources) (3) R's in series (at the right edge of the circuit) can be added. Now what's left is a Thevenin source and a Norton source. Convert the Norton source into another Thevenin source and you get two Thevenin sources in parallel to each other... which is very easy to analyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a very simple circuit, after making use of the following facts:

- Elements in parallel to a voltage source can be omitted
- Elements in series with a current source can be replaced by a short circuit

The voltage sources set the node voltage at node A to -5V, since two of them cancel each other.

At node B we have 5 currents, three are known. The other two can be written using the two node voltages VA and VB and the resulting equation can be solved. VA is already known, so only VB needs to be calculated.

The only resistors to care about are R4 and the two 50ohm resistors to the right. Everything else is unimportant.

Comment: yeah but why we omit the resistors that series with current source if there is a line like  

(Current source)---------Resistor-----Ground
wouldnt current flow through resistor ?

Comment: intermediate voltage is irrelevant

Comment: @onur cevik -- That was a bit sloppy. The series resistor can be replaced by a short circuit.

Comment: @Mario sorry my point was why are we doing that ? I mean why we are making it short circuit ? Wouldn't current from the source go through resistor.  sorry for my english.

Comment: Look at the branch with the 20mA current source. It injects a current of 20mA into node B and it draws a current of 20mA from the ground node. The resistor is unimportant, because the current source already sets the branch current. Whatever resistors value you would pick, the current source would account for it by adjusting its voltage.